# Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found., unable to find the mongod.service?

Tags: mongodb

I have followed all the answers mentioned in stackoverflow  still ima getting the same error as Failed to start mongod.service: Unit mongod.service not found.

how to solve this ? 
i have ubuntu cosmic and mongoDB version 3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've faced the some issue. 
here the solution 
please check that you have the configuration file for MongoDB `mongodb.service` in the main directory `/etc/systemd/system/`
if you couldn't found it just create it with 
`sudo vi /etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service`
then add the following content to the file

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Run the mongod service**

```
sudo systemctl start mongodb
sudo systemctl status mongodb
```

**Make the service permanent**

```
sudo systemctl enable mongodb
```

Comment: the problem was with the key they provided I removed everything from the system but still faced the same problem .thank you for the answer. I removed it again and installed the latest one, which solved my problem.

Comment: @BhanuBanda I am glad to hear that, sorry for the late answer

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `sudo service mongod start`

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/921753/failed-to-start-mongod-service-unit-mongod-service-not-found This link might help you

Comment: I followed the link and used this command 'sudo systemctl enable mongod' i am still getting the same Error

Comment: i have added a file called mongod.service  ,now i am getting another error as "Job for mongodb.service failed because the control process exited with error code".